# How to get reference for namespace Microsoft.WebPages.Compilation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC 3 web application. According to some articles, we can register global namespaces by CodeGeneratorSettings.AddGlobalImport function.[Here is one link.](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=570)

But the problem is I can not use CodeGeneratorSettings class in my app, can not find any references for it. Have it already been depreciated?

I have Webmatrix 1.0 installed, but it does not help.

Any help is appreicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method has been moved to the following namespace

```
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebCodeRazorHost.AddGlobalImport("Your namespace");
```

I would recommend using the web.config method however as there would only be one place in your code to add/remove namespaces.